# how to debug keycloak 22.0.9 in intellij idea on windows 10?

Tags: intellij-idea, keycloak

I clone keycloak 22.0.9 source code and build it with:

```
mvnw clean install -Pdistribution -DskipTests
```

successfully, then I open intellij idea (2021.3.2 version) to load it, after setup openjdk 17, I add new configuration in "Run/Debug configurations" dialog, choose "Application".

then I input "org.keycloak.testsuite.KeycloakServer" in "Build and run"-> Main Class, however, there is an error as below:
[image]

How to setup correctly in order to debug in intellij idea, thanks.

Note: the maven version is 3.9.6, nodejs is 20.11.0

Comment: You need to use "Remote Debug" configuration: https://www.keycloak.org/keycloak-benchmark/kubernetes-guide/latest/util/debugging-keycloak, https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/tutorial-remote-debug.html#create-run-configurations

Comment: @y.bedrow, thanks for you feedback. I just want to run keycloak as plain java application instead of in kubernetes environment nor in docker container.

Answer (score 0):

You should start this class instead: `org.keycloak.quarkus._private.IDELauncher`

Its purpose is to run locally Keycloak in dev mode.

Otherwise, you also have this class `org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.KeycloakMain` which is the real entrypoint.

The class `org.keycloak.testsuite.KeycloakServer` is meant to orchestrate the test suites.

Comment: thanks, but the second word (keycloak) is not recognized. It seems that all class of the keycloak are not recognized.